# Discover automatically neighbors using freedom js

Tags: javascript, freedomjs

I'm using [freedom js](http://www.freedomjs.org/) to create a P2P web application. Based in their documentation, says: *"No server-side code needed!"*.
But exist a way to discover the new peer connections and the disconnections to transfer data from a peer to another peer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this answer is releated with the version updated to Sep 29, 2015 .
And I sent an email to the owner:

> I'm currently wanting to build a simple application on top of freedom
>   js. Could you explain the architecture a little bit?
>
> How are the peers stored? What kind of DHT are you using? Is it
>   similar to a chord? or is it decentralized like bitcoin is?
>
> What I basically want to build is the basics of a p2p app such that,
>   this game can be played by A vs B, where no cheating would occur
>   because the matches are validated by log N neighbors. It would work
>   elimination style.
>
> So imagine a application 1v1 for simplicity sake that was p2p and a
>   million people using it. That means there would be approx 20 levels.
>
> 500,000 matches in level 1. 250,000 matches in level 2. 125,000
>   matches in level 3 . . . . 2 matches in level 18 1 match in level 19 1
>   winner at level 20
>
> Would this be possible in freedom js?

And the answer was:

> For context, freedom is a library that runs in the web browser of
>   individual users to help with managing a distributed application.
>
> We try to overlay on existing social networks rather than run our own,
>   so this is most relevant when you want something social - users
>   connecting to existing friends by linking the web app go Facebook /
>   Google / etc.
>
> Conceivably you could build a global network for connection on top of
>   a bitcoin like blockchain, but that hasn't been built yet. That seems
>   like the main piece of work needed from a technical perspective. In
>   terms off providing the sort of game experience in browser for a
>   distributed game like this.

In conclusion, not is possible yet use the specified features posted in my question.